# Creating an object from a class which is inherited ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance

Im struggling on understanding (after googling) on how to implement this: I have a class:

```
class Student
   # constructor method
   def initialize(name,age)
      @name, @age = name, age
   end

   # accessor methods
   def getName
      @name
   end
   def getAge
      @age
   end

   # setter methods
   def setName=(value)
      @name = value
   end
   def setAge=(value)
      @age = value
   end
end
```

And lets say I have another class which inherits from Student

```
class Grade < Student
   #constructor method
   def initialize(grade)
      super
      @grade = grade
   end

   # accessor methods
   def getGrade
      @grade
   end

  # setter methods
   def setGrade=(value)
      @grade = value
   end
end
```

I understand how to build an abject:

```
student = Student.new(name, age)
```

How can I build this `Student` (that I have just created) a `Grade` object associated with the student and how would I call the inherited object, for example i wanted to:

`puts 'student name and associated grade'`

I know I can place the grade variable within the `Student` class, but for the purpose of learning im doing it this way.

Comment: This code is to be rewritten from the scratch: 1. Getters and setters in Ruby should not be prefixed with this `get` and `set` garbage. 2. `Grade` should not be derived from `Student`. 3. The code to associate `Student` and `Grade` should be provided. I would suggest you to go through some Ruby tutorial, otherwise you are writing meaningless things that just can’t be corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, no need to define accessors in Ruby like that, it's far from idiomatic. Let's clean that up first:

```
class Student
  attr_accessor :name, :age

  def initialize(name, age)
    @name =name
    @age = age
  end
end

class Grade
  attr_accessor :value

  def initialize(grade)
    @value = grade
  end
end
```

Secondly it doesn't seem like `Grade` should inherit from `Student` at all, just adjust the latter to also store a `Grade` instance variable:

```
class Student
  attr_accessor :name, :age, :grade

  def initialize(name, age, grade = nil)
    @name =name
    @age = age
    @grade = grade
  end
end
```

You can then instantiate a student like this:

```
student = Student.new("Test", 18, Grade.new(1))
```

Or because of the default value you leave off the grade and assign it later:

```
student = Student.new("Test", 18)
# later
student.grade = Grade.new(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I access the grade value associated with the Student im trying something like puts student.Grade.grade

Comment: `puts student.grade.value`

Answer (score 2):

This code would do what you wanted:

```
class Grade
   attr_accessor :value
   def initialize value
     @value = value
   end
end

class Student
   attr_accessor :name, :age, :grade   
   def initialize name, age, grade
      @name, @age, @grade = name, age, Grade.new(grade)
   end
end

st = Student.new 'John', 18, 5
puts "student #{st.name} and associated grade #{st.grade.value}"
```